# Confused about what to show a matrix is an element of GL(2,$\mathbb{R}$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am kind of confused about what I am supposed to show in the following problem:

Show that for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$ \begin{pmatrix}
  cos \hspace1mm\theta& -sin \hspace1mm\theta \\
 sin \hspace1mm \theta & cos \hspace1mm\theta \\
 \end{pmatrix} \in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$$

Am I supposed to show that matrices of this form satisfy closure, associativity, existence of an identity and inverse? That is for matrices of this form, but with different $\theta$'s? I am not to sure what exactly it is asking.

Comment: You just need to show that they are invertible, i.e., they have non-zero determinant. This is easy to see since for any $\theta\in\Bbb R$, the determinant evaluates to $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1\neq 0$. Another (geometric) way to look at it is that it is a rotation matrix which rotates the plane by an angle $\theta$ which is invertible with inverse being the rotation matrix which rotates the plane by an angle $-\theta$

Comment: Related: The set $A$ of all such matrices (i.e., with determinant $1$) form a special subspace of $\operatorname{GL}(2,\Bbb R)$, called the _special linear group_ of real square matrices of order $2$, denoted $\operatorname{SL}(2,\Bbb R)$ (this can be generalized for $n\geq 2$).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas there is a follow up question that asks: show that GL(2, $\mathbb{R}$) contains elements of order n for any n $\geq$2. How would I go about this? What I did was take the matrix above with the arguments of $n \theta$ and set that matrix equal $I_n$. Then the only set of matrices of any order n$\geq$ 2 are those that have $n \theta = 2 \pi k$ for k = 0,1,2,3,..

Comment: Your thinking is on the right track. The matrices $A_\theta$ represent rotation of the plane by an angle $\theta$. Note that $A_\theta A_\alpha=A_{\theta+\alpha}$ and thus consequently, for any $n\geq 2$, the rotation matrix $A_{2\pi/n}$ has order $n$ since $(A_{2\pi/n})^n=A_{n\cdot 2\pi/n}=A_{2\pi}=I_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $GL(2,\mathbb R) = \{ A\in M_2(\mathbb R) : A$ is invertible$\}$, all you have to prove is that these matrices have determinant other than $0$.

Comment: Oh okay. Well I am glad I asked because that would have no occurred to me. It make sense now that you mention that.